# Why fragments do not necessarily correspond to pixels one to one?

Tags: opengl

Here is a good explanation what is a fragment:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8977/what-is-a-fragment/8981#8981

But [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63992/how-many-times-fragment-shader-is-executed) (and not only here) I have read that "I want to stress the fact that one pixel is not necessarily one fragment, multiple fragment can be combined to make one pixel....". But I don't understand clearly what are fragments and why they are not necessarily correspond to pixels one to one?

EDIT: When multiple fragments form one pixel it is only in the case when they overlap after projection, or it is because the pixel is bigger than the fragment, hence you need to put together next to each other multiple fragments with the same color to form a pixel?

Answer (score 5):

A fragment has a location that can be queried via its built-in `gl_FragCoord` variable where the `x` and `y` component directly correspond to pixels on your screen. So you could say that a fragment indeed corresponds to a pixel.

However, a fragment outputs a color and stores that color in a color buffer at its coordinates. This does not mean this color is the actual pixel color that is shown to the viewer.

Because a fragment shader is run for each object, it could happen that other objects are drawn after your first object that also output a fragment at the same screen coordinate. When taking depth-testing, stencil testing and blending into account, the resulting color value in the color buffer might get overwritten and/or merged with new colors.

Think of it like this:

```
Object 1 gets drawn and draws the color purple at screen coordinate (200, 300);
Object 2 gets drawn and draws the color red at same coordinate, overwriting it.
Object 3 (is blue) has transparency of 50% at same coordinate, and merges colors.
Final fragment color output is then combination of red and blue (50%).
```

The final resulting pixel could then be a color from a single fragment shader run, a color that is overwritten by many other fragment shader runs, or a combination of colors via blending.

Comment: My concern is why sometimes multiple fragments form one pixel? And is it possible the vice versa where one fragment will form multiple pixels?

Comment: Since each fragment outputs a color, if multiple fragment shaders were to run on the same screen coordinate (pixel), only the final fragment color would be the pixel color (unless you have blending in which case several fragments form the one pixel). 
As far as I know it is not possible to form multiple pixels with one fragment shader output (you can output to multiple color buffers at the same time, but that's a different topic)

Comment: I am kind of confused. When people say "...multiple fragment can be combined to make one pixel..." this means that for blending, depth and other reasons several fragments may form a pixel, but on the other hand in geometric form one fragment is equivalent to one pixel? I mean the size of the fragment is always equal to the size of the pixel when it is being rendered? And the coordinate of the fragment is always the coordinate of the pixel on the screen or it can be shifted a bit (e.g. 1/3 of a pixel size)?

Comment: Basically, the only thing a fragment is, is all the data required for OpenGL to render a pixel. The fragment shader takes this data and runs for each pixel of an object per object and outputs a color. The output of the fragment shader is then equal to a pixel value when an object is rendered. Will this output pixel value be the actual pixel value that the user sees? That depends on depth-testing,stencil-testing,blending etc. The coordinate of the fragment is indeed the coordinate of the pixel on the screen.

Comment: I guess CynicismRising thinks that the coordinate of fragment may not coincide with the coordinate of pixel, as he claims, that 4 fragments placed next to each other can form one pixel only. As I am really new in this area, I don't know what I have got wrong? Please help guys.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is not equal to a pixel when multi sample anti-aliasing (MSAA) or any of the other modes that change the ratio of rendered pixels to screen pixels is activated.

In the case of 4x MSAA, each screen pixel will be represented by 4 (2x2) fragments in the display buffer. The fragment shader for a particular polygon will only be run once for the screen pixel no matter how many of the fragments are covered by the polygon. Since a polygon may not cover all the fragments within a pixel it will only store color into the fragments it covers. This is repeated for every polygon that may cover one or more of the fragments. Then at the final display all 4 fragments are blended to produce the final screen pixel.

Comment: What is he meaning to have 4 fragment for 1 pixel? I don't get it.

Comment: The simplest answer is that the resolution of the render target does not have to equal the resolution of the screen or window.

In the case of 4x MSAA the resolution of the render target is 2x the window width and 2x the window height. Hence 4 fragments per screen pixel.

Comment: I wonder what happens if the render target is 1.34x the window width and 1.78x the window height? Of course, we need to operate with whole pixels, not half or other part. How this type of situation is being handled?